# Java: How to count the occurrences in a ArrayList with a method

Tags: java, arraylist

The method appearances() takes a number and an array of integers as its inputs and returns the number of times the number appears in the array.

Example:

```
    int[] arr = { 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 5 };
    System.out.println(appearances(3, arr)); // should print 4 since there are 4 3s
```

I first was suppose to write appearances() which I was able to do. Now I am trying to figure out how to do the same thing with an ArrayList instead.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 5 };
        ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int num : arr) { 
//this add the numbers from arr to arrList so pretty much making an ArrayList with the same numbers as the array
            arrList.add(num);
        }   
        System.out.println(appearances(3, arr)); 
        System.out.println(appearances(3, arrList)); 

        
    }


    public static int appearances(int datum, int[] nums) { 
//this is the method for find the occurrences for the array
          int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
                if (datum == nums[i])
                  count++;
            }
            return count;

    }   
    
    

    public static int appearances(int datum, ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
//this is the method for finding the occurrences for ArrayList
//this part is what I am asking help for
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
            if(nums.contains(datum)); 
                count++;
            }
        
        return count;
        


    }

}
```

For the method for the ArrayList I am getting 8 instead of 4, so I am guessing it is printing out the length of the arrayList instead. What am I missing?

Comment: I didn't get your question can you not find that using the length function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nums.contains(datum)` returns `true` if the list contains an element that is equal to `datum`. You want to check each element though.

Change:

```
if(nums.contains(datum));  // Note: ";" should be deleted too!
```

to:

```
if (nums.get(i).equals(datum))
```

Note that you had a trailing `;` which means your `if` does nothing if its condition is `true`.

However, it is easier and more idiomatic to use a foreach loop:

```
for (int i : nums) {
    if (datum == i)
      count++;
}
```

And of course there's the one line version based on a stream:

```
return (int)nums.stream().filter(i -> i == datum).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer you had a syntax error in your `if` declaration and this is why your code did not work properly. In addition to this I would also like to propose using Java 8 `Stream` to accomplish your task of counting the numbers present in a `List` in a single line:

```java
public void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = { 7, 3, 3, 6, 3, 3, 1, 5 };
    ArrayList<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int num : arr) {
        arrList.add(num);
    }
    System.out.println(appearances(3, arrList));
}

private static long appearances(int datum, ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
    return nums.stream().filter(i -> i.equals(datum)).count();
}
```

Comment: The errant `;` is *not* a syntax error: The code compiles and runs without error. It's an `if` without a body, which means no extra code runs when the `if` condition is true. It's nasty typo that can be hard to find,

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. So the rest of the code in the method is skipped when the `if` statement returns `true`?

Comment: No, not skipped. Everything runs. Think of it like the indentation is wrong: `count++;` and the next closing `}` should both be outdented 1 level to reflect reality.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the collections static method, or use stream API

```
public static int appearances(int datum, ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
int c1 = Collections.frequency(nums, datum);
int c2 = nums.stream().filter(x -> x==datum).count();
}
```